# 3D printed weapons and us

Tags: discussion, scope, legal

In the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79830/public-3d-printing-room) this had popped up:

> [Are questions related to DEFCAD's Liberator permitted here?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56705982#56705982)

After [asking on the main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359688/389668), I was asked to ask here instead. How shall we deal with the topic of 3D printed guns?

Comment: I think it's in the on-topic page, I vaguely remember seeing it today. Says off-topic (I think). Actually it should probably be moved it to the off-topic section at the bottom.

Comment: @Greenonline the "Legal issues" category lists "guns" as on topic,

Comment: Oh does it? Oh dear... Hmmm, not sure then,

Comment: @Greenonline I read that as questions about the legality are on topic (I think they are). It is not a carte balance about *how to print a barrel* or something

Comment: Ah, right. Yes, so a legal question is OK, but how to print is not? So that (partially) solves my question in the comment on your answer then.

Answer (score 2):

I think we should **not** allow asking about *manufacturing* 3D-printed fireams because it opens liability under NY law: The servers of SE are in NYC as is the company's incorporation. This means each user avails themselves to NY law under diversity jurisdiction - but the company is probably fine with [ToS #9](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service)... [New York **banned** *untraceable* 3D printed weapons and knowingly aiding in the manufacture of untraceable guns](https://www.nysenate.gov/newsroom/press-releases/senate-passes-gun-safety-legislation-ban-3d-printed-guns). Any 3D printed gun could be made untraceable by omitting one step in the manufacture that does have no structural impact - the addition of metal. So as a result any **knowing** assistance could be seen as causing the manufacture of an untraceable gun under New York Penal Code section 265.50 (Caps original, Emphasis mine):

> § 265.50 CRIMINAL  MANUFACTURE,  SALE,  OR  TRANSPORT OF AN UNDETECTABLE
> FIREARM.
>
> **A PERSON IS GUILTY OF CRIMINAL MANUFACTURE, SALE, OR TRANSPORT  OF  AN
> UNDETECTABLE FIREARM WHEN HE OR SHE KNOWINGLY** MANUFACTURES, **CAUSES TO BE
> MANUFACTURED**,  SELLS,  EXCHANGES, GIVES, DISPOSES OF, TRANSPORTS, SHIPS,
> OR POSSESSES WITH THE INTENT TO SELL:
>
> 1. ANY FIREARM, RIFLE, OR SHOTGUN THAT, AFTER REMOVAL OF GRIPS, STOCKS
>    AND MAGAZINES, IS UNDETECTABLE; OR
> 2. ANY MAJOR COMPONENT OF A FIREARM, RIFLE, OR SHOTGUN WHICH IS  UNDETECTABLE.
>
> CRIMINAL MANUFACTURE, SALE, OR TRANSPORT OF AN UNDETECTABLE FIREARM IS
> A CLASS D FELONY.

Comment: _"This means we avail ourselves to NY law"_ Who's "we"? If you mean the company, then you should probably have kept the Meta.SE question. Some users will disagree with you, but that should be fine. You might not get a definitive answer from Stack Exchange Inc. or not find a policy about this as others have suggested there, but that should be fine too. If you meant something else, you should probably clarify.

Comment: @ICloneable anyone who engages with such a question by answering. WE as in the community.

Comment: Well, in that case, the fact that the servers are in NYC is not really relevant. The community members are not employees in the company and I would imagine that most of them are not residents in NYC.

Comment: @ICloneable but interact with NY state in doing their "business", their actions of answering actions is happening (for the law) *in* NY.

Comment: To be honest, I think the mods would delete, not just close, any firearms questions that come up. Similar to if someone posted on Arduino "How can I make a bomb"? :-) However, what about 3D printed crossbows, or a spear, or club? Umm, this is getting murky now... IANAL, so I have no idea what we are meant to do actually.

Comment: @Greenonline Why does it have to imply criminality? A pyrotechnic might be developing a detonation device and might choose Arduino as their platform. It doesn't imply that it's criminal. In fact, printing 3D firearms is legal in the US (as long as you insert a special metal bar). There's a big difference between a legitimate question about legal firearm printing and a low-effort "how do I make a gun?" question.

Comment: @forest the world is much larger than the US, and it is illegal in New York State.